# Ram allocation for an application in android

Tags: android, memory-management

I am developing an Android application. Is it possible to allocate RAM for that application? For example: When my application opens it must allocate 30MB RAM. Mention the APIs.

Comment: You should really not try this. What are you trying to achive?

Comment: I am asked to to this. Its just a test application. Is that possible to allocate RAM space for the app?

Comment: Well you could use this `byte[] ram = new byte[mbCount * 1024*1024];`

Answer (score 5):

No you can't. This is entirely managed by the system.

In fact, the system will grow the heap allocated to your applicaton anytime it needs it. However, there is a limit by applicaton regarding memory consumption. To retrieve this limit, you can use the following :

```
/* Expressed in Megabytes */
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024
```

Finally, it appears you can specify in your manifest that your application is likely to be using more memory than a regular app by adding :

> [android:largeHeap="true"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap)

If you use this tag, look at [ActivityManager.getLargeMemoryClass()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getLargeMemoryClass%28%29) to verify the values assigned to your app. The returned value is expressed in megabytes. It *can* be higher than the value returned by [ActivityManager.getMemoryClass()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass()), given that your device's memory availabilty allows it.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that. Memory allocated to an application is specific to the device. I'd highly recommend that you watch [memory management video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) from Google IO 2011 to gain a deeper understanding of this topic.

Additionally take a look at the debug logs from logcat to understand how much memory is allocated to your app and how much of it remains.

> 01-13 14:37:54.538: D/dalvikvm(27390): GC_CONCURRENT freed 393K, 47%
>   free 3377K/6279K, external 2003K/2199K, paused 2ms+3ms

I'd not recommend using largeHeap="true" either. Like @Halim noted in his post the additional memory may not be allocated to your app anyway.

> Enabling this also does not guarantee a fixed increase in available memory, because some devices are constrained by their total available memory.

Focus on the need for 30MB of memory and how you can reduce it.